# use of :checked state in css for click action

Tags: html, css

The use of :checked state to define the action for clicked event is handy but is there a way to return to the unchecked or the normal state if we click else where in the window.

Comment: The `:checked` state ("pseudo-class") does not define an action; it refers to the state of a checkbox or radio button being checked, for use in a CSS selector. The `:checked` state can be removed only by the checkbox being unchecked by whatever means.

Answer (score 1):

That is a job of JavaScript, to change the element's state upon a change in some other element's event. CSS was never designed or developed to handle this type of situation.

You can use the `blur` event of the checkbox, to uncheck it. Like this

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').blur(function () {
   $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

..upon focus it will be checked and once the mouse is out of the focus (checkbox is not in focus) then it will be unchecked.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: But the checked state can be used to show/hide other elements using css itself

Comment: agreed! but they must only be the siblings or children. Must be with or next to each other in order for CSS to work with then.